# How can we back up KURA installation and configuration on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, backup, kura

I have installed KURA on my Raspberry Pi but my microSD card has been corrupted last week and I hade to re-install and re-configure KURA again after reformating the SD card.
I want to be able to back up my work, is it possible that I can copy KURA files on another location so in case the SD card get corrupted I manage to have it work again fast without the need to re-install and reconfigure it from zero.
Thanks in adavnce for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you apply a change in Kura, the changes are saved in a snapshot file. Each file is appended with a timestamp to denote the most recent change. These files are stored on disk at /opt/eclipse/kura/data/snapshots. If you have the latest snapshot backed up, you can:

1. Reinstall and start Kura
2. Open the Kura Web UI and navigate to Settings -> Snapshots
3. Use the 'Upload and Apply' button to upload your backed up file

Note: The snapshot files are encrypted on disk, to view them in plain text you must use the Kura Web UI to download the file. Also, you cannot manually copy the saved snapshot file to the new installation. You must use the Kura web UI to upload your file.

Thanks,
--Dave